# Can i print two statements with different conditions in a single if statement in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

In this code if a person if greater than 80 he/she should be displayed with different statement whereas the one with age greater than 18 different but if possible without adding anymore if statements

```
if  80 > given > 18:
    print("you are eligible for voting")
else:
    print("you are not")
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what output you desire.

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. You want to take more conditions into account without taking more conditions into account? Are you just looking for tricks to replace an ``if`` *statement* with something equivalent, such as an ``if`` *expression*?

Comment: [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 1):

Possible to do without ifs at all!

```
for age in (10, 19, 50, 88):
    print('age', age, 'is', ['<18', '18:80', '>80'][
        int((age - 18) / (80 - 18) + 1)])
```

Output:

```
age 10 is <18
age 19 is 18:80
age 50 is 18:80
age 88 is >80
```